# How can I check if an index for an array has been used already in a for loop (native JS)?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Currently, I am creating a random group generator and I am at a point where I am using a for loop to create the names. However, because I am using a random number using `Math.random()`, the same number can be returned and used as an index. This makes it so that one person in an array can be in multiple groups at a time, or even in the same group multiple times.

**Question**: How can I check if an index has already been used and stop it from being used?

JavaScript:

```
const inputArticle = document.querySelector('#input-article');
const inputForm = document.querySelector('#input-form');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const groupOptions = document.querySelector('select[ name="group-options" ]');
const createTeamsButton = document.querySelector('#create-teams-button');
const outputArticle = document.querySelector('#output-article');
const outputMainDiv = document.querySelector('#output-main-div');

let peopleArray = [];
let numberPeople = 0;
let rowNumber = 0;
let groupNumber = 1;
let maxPeopleInGroup = 0;
let maxNumberGroups = 0;

function addRow(person) {
    let row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    let removeButton = document.createElement("button");

    cell1.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell1.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell1.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell1.style.fontWeight = "300";

    cell2.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell2.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell2.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell2.style.fontWeight = "300";

    cell3.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell3.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell3.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell3.style.fontWeight = "300";
    
    removeButton.dataset = person;
    removeButton.innerText = `Remove ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
    removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        peopleArray = peopleArray.filter(p => p != person);
        row.remove();
    })

    cell1.innerText = person.firstName;
    cell2.innerText = person.lastName;
    cell3.appendChild(removeButton);
}

function createNames(event) {
    let person = {
        firstName:  document.getElementById(`firstName`).value,
        lastName: document.getElementById(`lastName`).value
    }

    event.target.reset();
    addRow(person);
    peopleArray.push(person);
    numberPeople++;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(peopleArray)); alerts array instead of giving [object, object]
}

function createOutput() {
    if (groupOptions.value != "") {
        //Hides the inputs and shows the outputs
        inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
        outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
        createGroups();
    }
}

function createGroups() {
    maxPeopleInGroup = groupOptions.value;
    maxNumberGroups = Math.floor(maxPeopleInGroup / peopleArray.length);
    let divWidth = 6 * maxPeopleInGroup;
    let divHeight = 7.5 * maxPeopleInGroup;

    while (numberPeople / maxPeopleInGroup > maxNumberGroups) {
        maxNumberGroups++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < maxNumberGroups; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", `group${groupNumber}`);
        div.style.width = `${divWidth}vw`;
        div.style.height = `${divHeight}vh`;
        //div.style.background = "red";
        //div.style.color = "blue";
        div.style.textAlign = "center";
        div.style.alignItems = "center";
        div.style.fontFamily = "Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif";
        div.style.fontSize = "18pt";
        div.style.fontWeight = "400";
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        outputMainDiv.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = `Group ${groupNumber}:</br>`;

        for (let k = 0; k < maxPeopleInGroup; k++) {
            // subtract k from the random possibilities and then add after to ignore previously 
            let index = Math.round(Math.random() * (peopleArray.length - k) + k)
            div.innerHTML += `${peopleArray[index].firstName} ${peopleArray[index].lastName} </br>`;
            //swap array elements
            let temp = peopleArray[k];
            peopleArray[k] = peopleArray[index];
            peopleArray[index] = temp;
        }

        groupNumber++;
    }
}     

inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        if (firstName.value && lastName.value) {
            createNames(event);
        }    
    }
}, false)

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
   createNames(event);
   event.target.reset();
})

createTeamsButton.addEventListener('click', createOutput);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Random Group Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <form method="dialog" id="input-form">
                <table id="table" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name:</th>
                            <th>Last Name:</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody></tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="first-name" type="text" required placeholder="First Name" id="firstName"></td>
                            <td><input name="last-name" type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName"></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit">Add Person</button>
                                <button type="reset">Clear Names</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table> 
            </form><br>

            <div id="options-group">
                <p>Number of people per group:&nbsp;</p>
                <select name = "group-options" required>
                    <option class="Options" value="">--Select Answer--</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="2">2</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="3">3</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="4">4</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="5">5</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="6">6</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="7">7</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="8">8</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="9">9</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="10">10</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="11">11</option>
                    <option class="Options" value="12">12</option>
                </select>
            </div>    

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="create-teams-button">Randomize Teams</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="output-article">
            <div id="output-main-div"></div>
        </article>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#input-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#options-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#input-article p {
    font-size: 18pt;
}

.Options {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#output-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#output-main-div {
    width: 100vw; /*Percentage width of browser*/ 
    height: 100vh; /*Percentage height of browser*/
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Just shuffle the array and draw from the new random order. Rather than try and generate random indexes that then you have to ensure don't clash. If size of the array is an issue, then generate and shuffle an array of indexes.

Comment: You could use an Object or Set to store indices used and then if the indices are in that, don't use them again.

Comment: [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810241/how-to-fisher-yates-shuffle-a-javascript-array)